# UIKit can't find UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Broke my head to resolving this issue:

[image: Reference UINavigationController]

Latest Xcode 8.3. In project only one class with this name, .m files are properly declared with same class name

Apricate for any help. Still stack in here

Comment: You should really post your code and warnings as a plain-text also (or only)

Comment: Are you working with iOS? How did you import the Telegram lib?

Comment: Yes, it is IOS.

Comment: Actually i just trying to customize Telegram source code, not lib

Comment: @VadimKotov Hi Vadim, actually this is source code of Telegram, just improved a bit.